# Python: Concatenate many dicts of numpy arrays with same keys and size

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, concatenation

I have a function called within a loop that returns a dict (dsst_mean) with roughly 50 variables. All variables are numpy arrays of length 10.

The loop iterates roughly 3000 times. I'm current concatenating towards the end of each loop so that I have an 'dsst_mean_all' dict that grows larger on each iteration.

```
source = [dsst_mean_all, dsst_mean]                
for key in source[0]:                    
    dsst_mean_all[key] = np.concatenate([d[key] for d in source])
```

It works, but I know this isn't efficient. I also have problems with initialization of the 'dsst_mean_all' dict. (I'm current using dict.fromkeys() to do this.)

My question is: what are some options to do this more efficiently? I'm thinking I could store the dsst_mean dicts in a list and then do one concatenate at the end. But I'm not sure if holding 3000+ dicts of numpy arrays in memory is a good idea. I know this depends on the size, but unfortunately right now I dont have an estimate of the size of each 'dsst_mean' dict.

Thanks.

Comment: Not only is it not efficient: it is terribly unsafe: you alter a dictionary you are iterating over. Your program can skip keys, iterate over a key twice, or even get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: So do you have any constructive suggestions?

Comment: Storing them as a list is fine, until you know that it's a memory issue.  It shouldn't add much overhead in terms of memory, and is much more efficient than creating numpy arrays each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we recommend collecting values in a list, and making an array once, at the end.  The new thing here is we need to iterate on the keys of a dictionary to do this collection.

For example:

A function to make the individual dictionaries:

```
In [804]: def foo(i):
     ...:     return {k:np.arange(5) for k in ['A','B','C']}
     ...: 
In [805]: foo(0)
Out[805]: 
{'A': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 'B': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 'C': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])}
```

A collector dictionary:

```
In [806]: dd = {k:[] for k in ['A','B','C']}
```

Iteration, collecting arrays in the lists:

```
In [807]: for _ in range(3):
     ...:     x = foo(None)
     ...:     for k,v in dd.items():
     ...:         v.append(x[k])
     ...:         
In [808]: dd
Out[808]: 
{'A': [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])],
 'B': [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])],
 'C': [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]}
```

Another iteration on the dictionary to turn the lists into some sort of array (`stack`, `concatenate`, your choice):

```
In [810]: for k,v in dd.items():
     ...:     dd[k]=np.stack(v,axis=0)
     ...:     
In [811]: dd
Out[811]: 
{'A': array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]), 'B': array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]), 'C': array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])}
```

A list of 3000 arrays of length 10 will take up somewhat more memory than one array of 30,000 numbers, but not drastically more.

You could collect the whole dictionaries in one list the first time around, but you still need to combine those into on dictionary like this.